# Coding in DART: Use a while loop to count the number of digits in a user inputed number

Tags: loops, dart, while-loop

I have been asked to write a program that uses a while loop to count the number of digits in a user inputed number. I have been watching tutorials and reading every doc I've come across and everything I have tried hasn't worked.
I can make it work by converting it to a string and using .length but I have to write it with a while loop.
I don't get any error messages, and with all the variations I've tried I just get an infinite printing of 0 or what looks like an infinite counting up.
Where am I going wrong with this?

````
  int num = int.tryParse(stdin.readLineSync());
  int digit = 0;

  while (num > 0) {
    digit +1;
    num / 10;
    print(digit);
  }```
````

Comment: You need to reassign to your variables, instead of `digit + 1;` for example, you could do `digit = digit + 1;` or the equivalent `digit += 1;`. You also need to reassign `num` when you divide by `10`. You also want to use integer division here `~/` rather than floating point division `/`

Comment: @mmcdon20 I figured it out. Thanks for your input :D